# how to push data from java class to Wso2 DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

Is there any document or step by step process which guides us on how we can use WS02 DAS to pull data from java class objects and display reports using this data using WS02 Dashboards.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First You can create an Event Stream by specifying attributes and mention what are the attributes you need to persist. When events arrives to the streams, those will be stored in Events tables [1].

Then you can create an Event Receiver for that Event Stream [2]. When creating an event stream you can use a protocol such as Thrift, Soap, Http, Mqtt, JMS, Kafka and Web sockets. You can write a simple Java Application to publish data to DAS Receiver you created on message format protocol which you have selected. For an instance if you create SOAP receiver you can use data on soap message format and also if you create a HTTP receiver you can use JSON format.

You can create a dashboard and gadgets to visualize Event table which was created by your persistent stream [3]. Please note that this event table consist all the events WSO2 DAS received, you can process these data by using spark SQL [4] and create several streams which could be used in Analytics Dashboard.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Understanding+Event+Streams+and+Event+Tables

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Configuring+Event+Receivers

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Analytics+Dashboard

[4] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Batch+Analytics+Using+Spark+SQL

Answer (score 0):

Your subject of the question and the body is contradictory. The subject says to push data while the body says pull data.

If push data is what you want to achieve, you can refer https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=45952633 This uses a thrift client to push data to DAS.

Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Analyzing+Data for how to analyze the raw data. You can write spark scripts for analyzing.

Finally you can https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Communicating+Results on how to analyze data. You may use the REST API exposed with DAS 3.0.0 to pull data from DAS.