# Java microservices (Spring Boot) push data to WSO2 DAS 3.0.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

There are many Spring Boot based Microservices in my organization, and most of them are Restful web services. To analyse and monitor them, the Microservices should be able to publish data to WSO2 DAS 3.0.1. Can anyone tell me where are step-by-step tutorials and documents available?

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Hi Sean, The following SO question might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607921/how-to-push-data-from-java-class-to-wso2-das

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support provided by WSO2 MSF4J for WSO2 DAS analytics can be used here with a few changes.

1. [DAS Setup](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/v2.0.0/analytics) -

WSO2 contain an analytics dashboard and SparkSQL scripts to analyze microservices data. (The jaggery app)

These were written with WSO2 MSF4J framework in mind, but the DAS setup guide can be extracted without much changes. You can use das-setup/setup.sh for this.

`sh das-setup.sh -d /path/to/das/home`

2. Write a Spring Boot interceptor that captures the requests and publish the events to DAS.

Your interceptor would look pretty similar to this [HTTPMonitoringInterceptor](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/blob/v2.0.0/analytics/msf4j-analytics/src/main/java/org/wso2/msf4j/analytics/httpmonitoring/HTTPMonitoringInterceptor.java).

Comment: Thanks a lot, will do.